Change the default localStorage structure
I have two different applications, mysite.com/app1 and mysite.com/app2. Both use similar localStorage keys. In browsers, the localStorage is directly under the domain "mysite.com". This causes the localStorage to get overriden when using both applications in different tabs.
Is there a way to differenciate the two localStorages, without using prefix for everytime.
Like can I make the localStorage under mysite.com/app1 and mysite.com/app2 separate?
I used different prefixes while accessing/setting data in localStorage, and that works, but I am looking for a different solution, where I don't have to use custom logic everytime I am interacting with my localStorage.

You can host two applications same domain but different sub domains

You can do followings,

You can host two applications same domain but different sub domains

create two functions which is set JSON string to local storage key and get the same string from it.


Getter
function getLocalStorage(key){

return JSON.parse(localStorage.get(key))

}

Setter
function setLocalStorage(key, value){

return localStorage.set(key, JSON.stringify(value))

}

You can just overwrite the setItem and the getItem in the index.js or app.js
var SetItem = localStorage.setItem; 
localStorage.setItem = function(key, value){
    SetItem.call(this, `PREFIX::${key}`, value);
}

var GetItem = localStorage.getItem; 
localStorage.getItem = function(){
    GetItem.apply(this, arguments);
}

localStorage.setItem("keyWithoutPrefix", "data")
console.log(localStorage.getItem("PREFIX::keyWithoutPrefix"))

Also you can overwrite is using Proxy object( this is much safer )
Storage.prototype.setItem = new Proxy(Storage.prototype.setItem, {
    apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
        return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentList);
    },
});

Storage.prototype.setItem = new Proxy(Storage.prototype.setItem, {
    apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
        return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentList);
    },
});

localStorage.setItem("key", "value")

console.log(localStorage.getItem("key"))


Yes this can be done, but my code base uses localStorage at thousands of places, and I was looking to avoid refactoring all of those locations. Any other way to handle this?

@FranshuYadav i have updated a sample.

Note that some applications also call .length, .key(number), .removeItem(string) and .clear() on Storage objects, these also need to be overriden

Add a new proxy function to those functions as well

@FranshuYadav if so can you mark it as an accepted answer ?
